# Web hosting start session problems

Tags: php

On my site, when a user logs ina session starts. On every page they go to, a function is called to see are they still logged in. If not, they are sent back to the login page.

I get a 500 Server Error and support are saying the reason the site is not working is this:

> ===========ModuleNameFastCgiModule Data1FASTCGI_RESPONSE_ERROR  Data2PHP Warning: session_start(): 
>   open(C:\Windows\TEMP\sess_dlsf4l5tu14labn4d77qbm1j21, O_RDWR) failed: 
>   Permission denied (13) in 
>   D:\hshome\myuser\domainname.com\login_success.php on line 2PHP Notice:
>   Undefined index: login in 
>   D:\hshome\myuser\domainname.com\login_success.php on line 5 ErrorCode5
>   ErrorCodeAccess is denied. (0x5)17:19code problem===========

They are telling me that it is a code issue, but it is working locally hosted with Apache web sever.

Login_success.php only contains a function to be called to see is the user logged in. On each page this page is included.

Basically I have a login page. It starts with

```
<?php
    session_start(); ?>
```

This page works but it doesn't do any PHP related stuff

from this it goes to check login.php

```
<?php     
 session_start();

 if(mysqli_num_rows($result) !=0 ){

    if($Account=="admin")
    {

        $_SESSION['username'] = $myemail;
        $_SESSION['login'] = '3';
        $_SESSION['AccountType']='admin';
        header("location:search.php");
    }

    else {
          $_SESSION['username'] = $myemail;
          $_SESSION['login'] = '1';
          $_SESSION['AccountType'] ='student';
          header("location:view.php");
     }}

    else {
    echo "Wrong Username or Password";
     $_SESSION['login'] = '2';
    header("Location: login.php");
    }
```

This  goes to view.php at the top there is

```
<?php
include 'login_success.php';
login();

      $link = mysqli_connect("ipaddress", "username", "pw", "dbname");



    // Check connection for an error

    if($link === false){

        die("ERROR: Could not connect. " . mysqli_connect_error());

    }

?>
```

and login success is

```
<?php
session_start();
function login(){

if($_SESSION['login']!='1')// This fxn checks to see if the user is logged in on the page
{
header("location:login.php");

}
}
function adminlogin(){
if($_SESSION['login']!='3') // This function checks to see if the user is logged in on the page
```

Comment: Is this hosted on a windows server? It looks like the php.ini config has no `session.save_path` or it has been setup incorrectly. It is incredibly unlikely that a hosted server would let you anywhere near the `C:\windows` folder

Comment: Yes , it is a windows sever.  And how would i got about configuring it?
I read on other questions that .temp is not allowing write permissions , but they told me it was? Can i re direct the path of session in some way, would that solve the issue?

Comment: I am surprised, a little naughty holding all the session files where other sharers of this shared host can access others session files.

Comment: Do you have access to the `php.ini` file?

Comment: Maybe you should show some of the code in case you have done something odd

Comment: When i login to my files all i see is /logs and /domainname.com and then all MY files that ive uploaded , is under domainname.com

Would redirecting my sessions , fix this issue , and if so , how can i ? Thanks for the help


also , its a shared hosting system. Tech support dont seem like the brightest sparks. When i was talking to them on the phone initially your man said he would have to ask the real tech support(essentially what he meant) , hadent  a clue about html dont mind php

Comment: no , i havent got access to php.ini. afaik

Comment: First line support are normally just dragged off the street and given a script

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/87321/discussion-between-riggsfolly-and-barry-burke).

Comment: `<?php
session_start();
function login(){

if($_SESSION['login']!='1')// This fxn checks to see if the user is logged in on the page
 {
  header("location:login.php");
  
 }
}
function adminlogin(){
 if($_SESSION['login']!='3')// This fxn checks to see if the user is logged in on the page
 {
  header("location:index.php");
  
 }
}

?>
`

Comment: Given the cost of a better web hosting service, I suggest you move on to a LAMP (Linux Apache Mysql Php) stack with a proper host. The time spent on this issue will more than cover for its cost. I'd suggest you look at web hosting providers such as gandi.net or dreamhost.com, bluehost.com etc. (I personally prefer Gandi but the others are already better than your current host).

Comment: But then, by the look of it, your code does not make much sense. Why 2 separate functions to check which type of login? Also, you shouldn't use mysqli anymore. Instead, go for PDO. Here is a tutorial: http://www.phpro.org/tutorials/Basic-Login-Authentication-with-PHP-and-MySQL.html

Comment: If you are not using any windows specific software i.e. just PHP and MySQL etc. then your PHP code can run on a 'linux' web host without much change. That is one of the useful points of PHP. It is how I develop here. I develop on Windows but host on Linux Hosting as it is less expensive.